How to stop Steam VR camera in Unity to peek through the wall, physically in virtual environment
Regardless of existance of colider, headset postion inside the wall makes player see through the wall.
1-1) I am using controller for movement(Vector2, touchpadposition). in moving with controller, colider works find and body stops when colision with other object occurs. This moves overall play area.
1-2) Player is standing up, but not walking. They use controller for movement and direction follows head mounted display(HMD). Player can turn and rotate their body and head. --> This is due to limited space. I am afraid I cannot alter this condition.
Unity Editor Image
2 ) However, if player bind their neck or walk away from start point(of play area which is moving with controller), colider is ignored and easily walk through and look through the wall. This happens because even though player asked to stand in one position, they tend to move slightly when they turn around. This little gap of start position and current position can cause the issue above happen.
3 ) I also tried "wall trigger and turn camera to black method" too, but this increases VR sickness of the player way too much so I had to give up that solution...
This lowers immersiveness, so I want to solve this problem.
If anyone knows how to make head colider work as well even with camera tracking so no more wall peeking happens, please share your ideas.
Or in opposit, if you let me know that will not gonna be possible also be helpful to me(I would love to hear detailed explanation, if possible).
I am not fully understand how the steamVR headset tracking and unity communicating to get pos and rot of the headset for virtual environment. So even if there is no full answer to this, any opinion or idea that I might missing will be very helpful to me.
Thank you!

A well known issue as you can not restrict the real players movement -> ensure things are far enough away from where the player physically can move to, or make the walls "thick enough" so it is no use to bend into it .. you will only see the "inside" of the wall

Thank you. That is also one of my considerations. However, usual unity objects such as cubes, still show through beyond regardless of how thick it is. So one of my options is to add a second layer of wall that frequently penetrates to make them at least not see-through outside. I'll try that one too. Thank you again for your opinion.

Yeah double sided walls is what I mean + making them thick enough (like e.g. 0.5-1m) beyond where your users can physically move to

Another technique is to push the player back from the wall. Some people get motion sickness from this, some don't.

That is an interesting idea. Do you mean when a player's headset is triggered with a wall then calculates the vector and pushes the player with opposite vector direction? Motion sickness is indeed one big issue though...
